# How can I add handler to database query results in Lithium

Tags: php, mongodb, lithium

I am using the Lithium framework version 1.1.1 in PHP 5.6 with MongoDB. I have updated MongoDB from 3.4 to 3.6 and this ended up requiring the PHP ini variable `mongo.long_as_object` be set to `true` for the `aggregateCursor()` methods to work properly in the legacy MongoDB driver for PHP. This version of Lithium does not yet support the newer MongoDB PHP module. This causes a problem with the way `NumberLong` values are handled in Lithium since they are converted to a `MongoInt64` in PHP.

For example: When calling `$results->data()` on a `DocumentSet`, a BSON result such as `{ viewers: NumberLong(12345) }` will decode to `[ 'viewers' => [ 'value' => '12345' ] ]`. Instead I need the PHP array to be `[ 'viewers' => 12345 ]`.

If I add an appropriate handler directly in the `lithium\data\entity\Document::_init` method then everything works as I expect. For example:

```
$this->_handlers += [
    'MongoId' => function($value) { return (string) $value; },
    'MongoDate' => function($value) { return $value->sec; },
    'MongoInt64' => function($value) { return (int) $value->value; }
];
```

However, directly editing the Lithium library is likely not the best approach especially when upgrading the library to newer version as they are released. Is there a proper way to add this handler elsewhere? Such as in the `Connections::add(...)` method in the connections.php bootstrap file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, handlers aren't directly configurable, however, they're not too hard to override. You can pass a `classes` key to `Connections:add()`, which allows you to extend one of the two classes where handlers are specified, i.e.:

```
Connections::add([
    /* ... */,
    'classes' => [
        'entity' => 'my\data\Document'
        // -- or --
        'schema' => 'my\data\Schema'
    ]
]);
```

From there, you can implement your custom class that extends the appropriate core class, adding extra handlers as appropriate. Also, a PR to add `MongoInt64` support to Li3 core would be gratefully accepted. :-)